# Помогите исправить ошибку в коде Python socket

Tags: python, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер, client

Помогите исправить ошибку в коде Python, код запускается но при вводе команды в server и ее дальнейшей отправки клиент должен смотреть что это за команда и давать ответ в зависимости от того что это за команда но вместо этого команда всегда переходит к else

у меня Python 3.8 работаю в Python IDLE

вот код:

server:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(

    socket.AF_INET,
    socket.SOCK_STREAM, 

)

server.bind (


    ("127.0.0.1", 5555)

)

server.listen()


while True:
    user_socket, address = server.accept()

    def TEST():
        command = input ("plese input command ")
        if command == ("test"):
            user_socket.send("test".encode("utf-8"))
            TEST()

        else:
            user_socket.send("test_12345".encode("utf-8"))
            TEST()

    TEST()
```

client:

```
    import socket

client = socket.socket(

    socket.AF_INET,
    socket.SOCK_STREAM, 
)

client.connect(
    ("127.0.0.1", 5555)
)

while True:

    data = client.recv(2048)
    command = data
    if command == ("test"):
        print ("TEST")

    else:
        print ("TEST_12345")
```

Comment: Странный код с `TEST()`, не вижу причины тут использовать функцию и тем более рекурсивно. И скобки ненужны в `("test")`, т.е. просто `if command == "test":`

Comment: я использовал функцию чтоб можно было запрашивать ввод команды несколько раз, чтоб не надо было после каждой введеной команды перезагружать сервер

Comment: Засуньте код в еще один цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проверка на сервере и клиенте одинаковая: `if command == ("test"):`, но данные в `command` будут разные.

На сервере в `command` будет строка, т.к. `input` вернет строку.

На клиенте в `command` будет **байтовая** строка, т.к. по сокетам байты передаются. А т.к. `b"test"` не будет равной `"test"`, то условие попадает в `else`. Вы, кст, на сервер строку отправляете как байты (метод `encode` возвращает байты).

Попробуйте на клиенте сделать так:

```
    ...
    data = client.recv(2048)
    command = data.decode("utf-8")
    if command == "test":
    ...
```